# Laravel-5 how to count row on stored procedure select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I count the number of rows returned on the following stored procedure select in Laravel-5?

```
$bookings = DB::select('call bookings_by_voucher()');
```

I have tried `$bookings->count()` but such doesn't exist as `$bookings` is an array.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHPs count function

```
count($bookings);
```

[docu](http://php.net/manual/de/function.count.php)

Comment: Yes I know but is there no supported Laravel function?

Comment: I don't think so. In my opinion there is no need for a helper / implemented method to count an array.

Comment: I guess it would need to be selected and returned as an object then.  Do you know how I could do a `DB:raw` select and return as an object then?

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184849/laravel-from-raw-db-to-eloquent)

Comment: @V4n1ll4 What are you trying to achieve, that `count()` would not be adequate and you would need to get the array's size from a method?

Comment: It's ok I have decided to use the count() function.

Comment: Count by php will retrieve the dataset from SQL making it slow.

Answer (score 0):

Stored function must return result, procedure may return result if it's coded inside. They're not tables so You can only get size of result. Procedures, functions are effective with control flows inside of it, when next query will be done according result of previous query, it's better when You're sending many queries to do some logic and You're pushing traffic between db and app many times. So with procedures, functions You do send request to db once and get result of heavy logical operations. But if it consist only one request You better create **view** that does this query.

Read about procedures, functions, views here: http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=28